# Are images formed due to reflection or refraction and what do we see? HOW?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, speed-of-light, reflection, refraction

I am getting extremely confused about what we see as individuals : do we see reflected rays or refracted rays and what does our brain interpret?
The concept has bewildered me for a long time. Googling out was not of much benefit.

Comment: 'images are formed due to reflection' - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Is your intent to discuss virtual images only?

Comment: @ThePhoton i m now much more confused about whats an image :(

Comment: Where the ray originating on one location of the object meet is the image. If that's on the output side of the optical element (so the rays actually do converge there and would form an image on a screen placed there) it's a *real image*. If the rays converge on the other side of the optical element (so there's no actual light there), then it's a *virtual image*. It doesn't matter whether the optical element is a mirror or a lens.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to realize here is that your eye is really stupid.  It doesn't know about the difference between real and virtual images, or about the difference between images and objects, or about the difference between emitted light or reflected light, or even about the existence of lenses or mirrors.  Your eye is a simple machine which does exactly one thing reasonably well:

> If light rays are diverging from some point in space, your eye tells your brain that there is a light source there.

[image: Image from converging lens][[source]](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-5/Converging-Lenses-Ray-Diagrams)

In this illustration, and object on the left side is emitting/reflecting light (the blue lines).  If you stood on the left side of the lens, you'd see the object itself.  With the lens in the way, however, the blue light rays all get bent (red rays) so that they all pass through the same region in space.  If you stand off to the right, where the eyes are in the illustration, you see diverging light from the *right* side of the lens.  Your stupid eye informs your brain that there's a light source between the eye and the lens: an image.  (You can see this image for yourself by holding a magnifying glass at arm's length and looking through it at stuff that's across the room.  The image is inverted, and kind of hard to focus on.)

[image: Virtual image from a converging lens]

Here's another illustration (from the same source, but not quite as nice) that shows the same sort of lens, but a different geometry.  Now the red rays appear to all be diverging from a point, but that point is *behind the lens*.  Your stupid eye doesn't care.  Your stupid eye tells your brain that there's a big tall arrow behind the lens, because your stupid eye only knows about the diverging light that reaches it.

[You can do the same thing with curved or flat mirrors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/mirray.html).  No matter how the light has been massaged on its way to you, your stupid eye will look at how the light is diverging and extrapolate backwards to find "a source." That source is "an object" if there's a physical thing there; a "real image" if real light actually passes through the source as in my first illustration; and a "virtual image" if, as in the second illustration, no light actually passes through the image's location.